# I need to change my wordpress theme's add on to my desired design

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is my first topic here. I need help with my WordPress theme. This is my site I need the help with, https://assetbangla.com/

Here there is an advanced search option at the beginning of the site. Like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZmiL.jpg

Now I want this to look like this in both desktop and laptop. https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7nWU.jpg

And on the mobile, I need to fix this. Right now it’s showing distorted…
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv8s5.jpg

Please help me with this. It will be a world to me. Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Getting useful answers is typically dependent on asking minimal, verifiable questions that provide the examples of the actual code your are working with. Can you isolate the HTML and CSS of the search feature and provide it here? Or even create a minimal example here that behaves similarly enough. There are lots of great resources here to help you form your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Given the class name "wppb-builder-container" it looks like the plugin "[Profile Builder](https://www.cozmoslabs.com/wordpress-profile-builder/)" by Cozmolabs was used to create this form. In that case you should find a "Profile Builder" section in your admin area:

[Screenshot of Profile Builder in Wordpress admin area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9yFF.png)

You can find the documentation for the plugin here:
https://www.cozmoslabs.com/docs/profile-builder-2/

And you can reach the support of Cozmolabs here:
https://www.cozmoslabs.com/support/open-ticket/

Comment: Thanks for your comment but there is no Profile Builder section in the admin panel nor the Plugin of Profile Builder is installed. This is the theme I am using here... https://themeforest.net/item/realesta-property-sales-rental-wordpress-theme/23551722?_ga=2.109163461.175359947.1559392949-1275296847.1556047236

Comment: @Diverter I think you can ask the makers of the theme directly: https://themeforest.net/item/realesta-property-sales-rental-wordpress-theme/23551722/support